# Java Changing State

Tags: java

`i` represents rows and `y` represents columns in a connect 4 game, I am trying to change the color of the circle depending on the column the user has selected but this code keeps giving an error type mismatch cannot convert state to string.

```
public enum State{
    RED, YELLOW, BLANK;
}
```

Comment: Post the variables' declarations, the whole error, and specify in which line it is raised

Answer (score 2):

*Exactly* as the error message says, `f` should contain Strings, as your declaration states:

```
public static void dropRedCounter (String[][] f)
                                   ↑
```

But you're comparing its value to a `State`, and you're also trying to assign a `State` to it:

```
f[i][y] = State.RED;
```

You might want to have `State.RED.name()` in order to have the String value of the Enum.

See the docs for further details: [Enum Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Answer (score 0):

You try to assign an enum to a string.
try `f[i][y]=State.RED.toString()` for saving it and `State.valueOf(f[i][y])` to get the enum from a string. Another approach is to have an array of enums(just use search, i'm sure you will find something)

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly compare an enum value and a string, or assign an enum value to a string. However, you can convert the enum into a string and compare them then:

```
if (f[i][y].equals(String.valueOf(State.BLANK)) {
```

Similarly for the next line:

```
f[i][y] = String.valueOf(State.RED);
```